# Can I use the word “Senior” as part of a job title directly in German?

Tags: translation, anglicism

I prepare my CV in German and I want to say *Senior Design Engineer* and *Senior Engineer.*

On Stack Exchange, I saw that *erfahrener* was used for *senior*.
However, on the Internet, mostly, people direct *senior* directly, for example:

> Senior Engineer → Senior Ingenieur

How can you say *Senior Design Engineer* and *Senior Engineer* in German?

Comment: Sidenote: Consider thinking about whether you want to translate the title in the first place. Probably everybody reading your CV can understand the English version of your title and it is more accurate than any translation can ever be.

Comment: My Grandfather worked for Mercedes Benz in Germany for 50 years. I do know that his close friends (and sometimes Grandma) would call him Ingenieur or Meisteringenieur.

Answer (score 10):

If you present yourself as

> Senior Design Engineer

i.e. with an English job title, the *Senior* is of course fine.

If you want to use German terms you can say

> Leitender Entwicklungsingenieur *)

but that would be pretty unusual. Today, in the larger industries, almost everything is called by English names, just glued together with some German grammar. The big boss in a company is today almost invariably a *CEO*, nobody calls himself a *Generaldirektor* any more (that's a term from about 100 years ago).

Still, if your job title is not that specific, you might prefer a genuine German title such as

> Leitender Ingenieur  :-)

instead of

> Senior Engineer   :-(

And of course, for jobs that have traditional, well-established German titles you use those. You would not present yourself as a

> Baker, Carpenter, Machinist

but as a

> Bäcker, Tischler, Dreher (or Industriemechaniker or whatever)

---

*) If that's what it is. I am not in design engineering. But dictionaries say design engineer is Entwicklungsingenieur. I personally would have guessed *Produktdesigner*, but I may be totally wrong with that idea.

Comment: I agree with Christian's answer - terms not often used today are Senior Engineer= *Oberingenieur* or *Leitender Ingenieur* (as said above) and for Senior Design Engineer = *Leitender Konstrukteur*.

Comment: With job titles, it's always a good idea to look into the requirements needed to use a specific title. For example, I know of an "Ingenieur" who had to go to court to clarify whether or not he is allowed to call himself "Diplom-Ingenieur". Another example is the difference between "Fußpfleger" and "Podologe". And a German politician had to stop referring to himself as "Doktor" some time ago, because he got his Ph. D. from a foreign university and it wasn't recognized in Germany.

Additionally, it's worth to mention that "Senior" on its own refers to senior citizens :D

Comment: A "senior engineer" is not necessarily a "Leitender Ingenieur". "Leitend" very clearly implies (non-technical) authority, whereas "senior" doesn't.

Comment: @tofro  Totally possible. As I said, I am not an expert in these vocations and their titles. The question was if using English terminology is acceptable in German CVs, and when and/or when not. On the other hand: where there is a Senior Engineer, there would probably also be some non-senior ones, and whether authority is technical or managerial... well, that's often a bit of a mix, anyway, no? For selecting the best German title, we would need to know what exactly in this context (in this company) a Senior Engineer implies. Only an embellishment of the title? Or a real position?

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't *Senior* alone. It's also *Ingenieur*. What English speakers call an engineer is often enough a *Techniker* in German. In general

- you are a *Techniker* if you did a vocational training and/or attended a trade school.
- you are an *Ingenieur* if you studied at a technical university.

Technically the latter is *Diplom-Ingenieur* but no one but Austrians talks like that. (And there are exceptions as e.g. the *Schiffsingenieur* which is a naval officer.) Also, Bologna reforms added Bachelor and Master Of Science to that mingle, which aren't translated either.

If you did a computer science major at an university, you aren't an *Ingenieur* in German at all, but an *Informatiker*. The *Diplom-* et al is skipped in everyday talk, and put as *Dipl.-Inf., Informatiker (BSc), Informatiker (MSc)* in writing.

So … your job title isn't translateable at all. Do not translate it.